# Why still having Permission Denied in Android with file 777 permission

Tags: android, xml, permissions, permission-denied

I try to read/write a file `data_quizz.xml` situated in `/data/data/com.my.package.app/files/data_quizz.xml`. Using other topic I used adb to make `/data` and all subfolders in the `data_quizz.xml` path 777.

But when it comes to this line :

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.my.package.app/files/data_quizz.xml");
```

I still get an error, this is the stacktrace :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.my.package.app/files/data_quizz.xml (Permission denied)
     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:99)
     at com.dautry.a16126734.quizzapp.XmlManager.<init>(XmlManager.java:43)
     at com.dautry.a16126734.quizzapp.ChooseTopic.onCreate(ChooseTopic.java:27)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

*Edit : Correction of the initial path which were wrong*

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to ask permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: **Never hardcode paths**. That path will be wrong on millions of devices. Also, it is a very unusual location (`files/` *inside* of `databases/`???). I recommend that you try more conventional approaches, such as `openInputStream("data_quizz.xml")` or `new File(getFilesDir(), "data_quizz.xml")`. "Using other topic I used adb to make /data and all subfolders in the data_quizz.xml path 777" -- I doubt that will help. You may have messed up the permissions; I recommend doing a full uninstall of the app before proceeding.

Comment: No permissions needed for internal memory.

Comment: That looks like a non existing path. Use the File class to check if the file exists before you call that code. Use File.exists().

Comment: Thanks for answering ;)
@PhạmLam Yeah to be sure I put READ/WRITE external device permition.I made a mistake the path is /data/data/com.my.package.app/files/data_quizz.xml my mistake. Yeah you're right i'll put some conventionnals ways thx

Comment: @greenapps I try to add just `new File(getFilesDir(), "data_quizz.xml")` to check if it founds the file and it does. This line doesn't throws exceptions.

Comment: That does not check anything. And it will never throw exceptions. And i see no .exists() function! Put your new code in your post. Not in comments.

Comment: @greenapps Hum okay my bad! If I had the `exist()` it return false. So I guess it doesn't find the `File(getFilesDir(), "data_quizz.xml")` :/

Comment: The file does not exist then. You can see the full path with file.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: Yes you're right the path the `file.getAbsolutePath()` returns is `/data/user/0/my.package.name.app/files/data_quizz.xml`. So should I try to move my file here?

Comment: Dont know. All is up to you.